# How to update to the latest floating version with lock file in dotnet?

Tags: .net, nuget, dotnet-restore

I have project that references a nuget package. Here is a snippet from `.csproj` file:

```
<RestorePackagesWithLockFile>true</RestorePackagesWithLockFile>
...

<PackageReference Include="MyPackage" Version="1.*" />
```

Now after the restore the lock file is created and a version is locked, e.g. 1.0.1. What I want to do now is to force to reevaluate floating version after I publish a new package. I did not manage to achieve that, whatever I call, the version stays the same. This is what I tried, but to no avail:

```
dotnet restore -f --force-evaluate --no-cache
```

I use `Rider` and tried to do that in the GUI by clicking restore there. It does work but not at once, I have to wait some time before a new version is detected until it's getting restored. I did not manage to figure out what command `Rider` issues to do the update or why it does not work at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently deleting of the `packages.lock.json` works just fine, but it's hardly a very good solution, so I still hope for a better answer.

Comment: Did you found a better way meanwhile? Currently facing a similar issue when you have multiple projects, if a refenced project in the same solution contains nuget packages with floation versions these are not respecting the floating version logic but it's always taking the one with the lowest version number.

Comment: No, I did not, do not know why it works like that...

Comment: Just to come back to this topic. Today I noticed the command dotnet restore --force-evaluate was working with a colleague of mine.
The fix is to update your active dotnet cli to a version more recent than 10 may 2022.
Once I had the most recent SDK it all started working as supposed.